# Modify Sqlite Database Structure in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web app in Flask which is using a SQLite database via SQLAlchemy.
As I'm building, I'm finding that I need to create additional tables and/or modify tables as I go.
In other projects (PHP) this was easy to do, as I could just modify the database using PHPMyAdmin. But with Flask SQLAchemy, I'm finding that I have to delete the sqlite file and then re-create it using "db.create_all()". This method is frustrating as I want to retain the sample data that I have in the database.

What is the recommended way to easily modify a sqlite database structure when using with Flask SQLAchemy?

Thanks,
Hugh.

Comment: Learn how to patch a database. You do not erase everything. But you alter table, add column, migrate.

Comment: [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)